# Do we need an "I f the sourcecode, you f the input" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

A somewhat common pattern in [source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout) is to have competitors write a program which does task A (usually cat or printing a constant), but when a transform B is applied to the program the modified program does B applied to A.

Here are a bunch of examples, (they also have very similar titles):

- [Mirror quine (or my head hurts)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/16043/56656) [tag added] (and its duplicate [I reverse the source code, you reverse the source code!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/265566/56656)) [tag added]
- [Period 2 Reversed Quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/118884/56656)
- [I double the source, you double the output!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132558/56656) [tag added]
- [I shift the source code, you shift the input!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/196864/56656)
- [I reverse the source code, you reverse the input!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/193315/56656)
- [I transpose the source code, you transpose the input!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/193331/56656)
- [Pass on your radiation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/197051/56656)
- [I palindrome the source code, you palindrome the input!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/221209/56656)
- [I (rev)?(pal)? the source code, you (rev)?(pal)? the input!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/265514/56656)
- [I Rot-13 the source code, you Rot-19 the output!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/221225/56656)

Here are some marginal examples:

- The transform applied to the source and the output are similar but not the same:

  - [Make an interweaving quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/104882/56656)
  - [I reverse the source code, you negate the output!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/192979/56656)
  - [I reverse the source code, you negate the input!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/193021/56656)
- Fits the description by virtue of the fact that the source and the output are the same thing:

  - [Radiation softened quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/73657/56656)
  - [Russian Nesting Quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/154629/56656)
  - [Unfurling-Safe Quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/140099/56656)

This seems like a good candidate for a tag:

- There are a number of similar challenges.
- They have been posted with some degree of regularity for an extended period of time (6 years since the first, the most recent was posted this week).
- There seems to be substantial room for novel challenges in the format.
- They are not easy to find using an existing combination of tags. (The titles are pretty formulaic, but hard to search and there is at least one example of a challenge in the group which does not use the format.)

So then:

- Is there a good reason not to make this tag?
- What should the criteria for this tag be? i.e. what should the tag wiki say?
- What is a good name for this tag?

Comment: [tag:source-transformation] perhaps?

Comment: The cheeky version would be [f-the-source-f-the-output], which can be read as "f\*\*k up the source, f\*\*k up the output" :P  Especially for challenges like Wheat's recent radiation challenge: [I irradiate your source code, you irradiate your output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/265644)

Comment: I suggest to edit this post with `[tag added]` once [the new tag](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/source-transformation/info) has been added to a challenge.

Answer (score 16):

## Yes

It makes sense to have a tag for this kind of challenge, since there are so many of them, they share a common challenge aspect, and the aspect is unique from other kinds of [source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout) challenges. I propose [source-transformation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-transformation), since the challenge is about transforming the source.

Comment: I created [tag:source-transformation], added basic tag info, and added the tag to [I double the source, you double the output!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132558/56656). I don't want to mass edit a bunch of challenges all at once to add the tag, though.

Comment: @mbomb007 I still would have liked to answer the very important question of "What should the criteria for this tag be?" before adding the tag.